# What kinds of functions preserve inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given real numbers $a, b, c$ such that $$a < b < c$$ if $f$ is a function that satisfies $$f(a) < f(b) < f(c)$$ for all $a, b, c$, then what can be said about $f$?

I thought that such an $f$ would have to be [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). But I also thought that $f(x) = x^2$ is monotonic **(edit: it's definitely not monotonic)**, and it doesn't satisfy the above inequality for all $a, b, c$ (for example, $a = -3$, $b = -2$, and $c = -1$).

Could someone list all of the general requirements for a function that preserves inequalities?

Comment: How is $x\mapsto x^2$ monotonic?

Comment: $x^2$ is not monotonic on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Oh shoot, that's definitely right. Then is monotonicity the *only* requirement for a function that preserves inequalities?

Comment: $x\mapsto x^2$ is monotonic on the interval $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Not just monotonicity, but being strictly increasing, is the requirement you're looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x^2$ **is not** monotonic, for exactly the reason you observe. Indeed, a monotonic function *by definition* either always preserves or always reverses the order of the inputs ... in the *weak* sense (of $\le$ rather than $<$).

What you want are the *strictly increasing* functions: these are just those functions satisfying $$a<b\implies f(a)<f(b).$$ More generally:

- $f$ preserves $\le$ iff $f$ is nondecreasing.
- $f$ reverses $\le$ iff $f$ is nonincreasing.

(These two cases correspond to monotonicity.)

- $f$ preserves $<$ iff $f$ is increasing.
- $f$ reverses $<$ iff $f$ is decreasing.

(I've heard these two cases called "strongly monotonic.")

Here by "increasing" etc. I mean "increasing *everywhere*" etc.

Comment: So monotone functions preserve $\geq$ and $\leq$, while *strictly* increasing functions preserve $<$ and $>$ -- is that correct?

Comment: @sawghol That's right. Note that if you preserve $<$ (respectively, $\le$) you automatically preserve $>$ (respectively, $\ge$).

Comment: Very helpful -- thank you!

Comment: "Monotonic" simply means that the function is either increasing or decreasing.  Some authors use monotonic to mean *strictly* increasing or decreasing, while others use monotonic to mean either nondecreasing or nonincreasing.  It is worth checking the index to see what the author of any particular text *actually* means.

Comment: @XanderHenderson That's a good point. I've much more frequently seen it used to refer to the weak version, but it is definitely used both ways.